# Как изменить ActionBar из другого Activity?

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Есть в ActionBar (кнопка) item zakazBar

```
zakazBar = menu.findItem(R.id.zakazBar);
```

В родном Activity1 я делаю

```
zakazBar.setVisible(true);
```

И моя кнопочка становится видимой!

Внимание вопрос! В Activity2 есть такой же ActionBar и мне из Activity1 нужно сделать item видимым  `zakazBar2.setVisible(true);`

Но в Activity1 `zakazBar2 = menu.findItem(R.id.zakazBar2);` не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Единственный способ - передавать информацию при запуске активити.

1) В первой активити создаём Intent ко второй активити

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
```

2) Пихаем в него флаг

```
intent.putBoolean("key", true);
```

3) Во второй активити при запуске считываем флаг и устанавливаем видимость.

```
zakazBar2 = menu.findItem(R.id.zakazBar2);
zakazBar2.setVisible(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("key", true);
```

А ваш вариант не работает, т.к. нема у первой активити никакого доступа ко второй и вы никак не можете там что-то поменять кроме вышеописанного способа.

**UPD_0:**

Можно и иначе. Как писал @pavlofff (c моими дополнениями):

В первой активити устанавливаем флаг в зависимости от какого то условия (для примера в коде: если a=0 - показывать иконку, иначе нет)

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putBoolean("isShow", ((a==0)? true:false));
edit.commit();
```

Во второй активити читаем этот флаг и либо показываем иконку, либо нет:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    zakazBar2 = menu.findItem(R.id.zakazBar2);
    zakazBar2.setVisible(sp.getBoolean("isShow", false));
}
```

Делать же это в **onCreate**() не надо, т.к. меню может быть ещё не создано (иногда оно создаётся даже после **onResume**(). Надо там, где меню создаётся, т.е. в **onPrepareOptionsMenu()**

Comment: При долговременном сохранении состояния видимости этой иконки интент не подходит. То есть он может один раз установить видимость, а потом несколько раз вызывать `активити2`, возможно и не из `активити1` - при последующих вызовах интент может быть потерян/ Решение с преференсами более надежное.

Comment: @pavlofff, да, согласен, добавил в ответ с изменениями. В onCreate() как у вас меню ещё может быть не создано.

Answer (score 3):

Активити не имеют прямой связи между собой. По факту вообще существует только та активити, которая видима в данный момент на экране и вы, по понятным причинам, не можете изменять `ActionBar` в том, чего еще (или уже) нет - при следующем появлении активити будет создана заново, а те, что становятся невидимы - условно можно считать, что будут утрачены.

Наиболее разумно, в вашем случае, использовать флаг состояния в `SharedPreferences`. В первом активити этот флаг устанавливается в значение `true` - показать иконку, либо `false` - не показывать иконки - во второй активити флаг читается и по его состоянию либо показывается, либо нет эта иконка.

В первой активити устанавливаем флаг в зависимости от какого то условия (для примера в коде: если a=0 - показывать иконку, иначе нет)

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putBoolean("isShow", ((a==0)? true:false));
edit.commit();
```

Во второй активити читаем этот флаг и либо показываем иконку, либо нет:

<strike>`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`</strike>

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
zakazBar2.setVisible(sp.getBoolean("isShow", false));
```

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ с изменениями. В onCreate() как у вас меню ещё может быть не создано. Засим лучше меню менять в onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Comment: Да, точно .. я на автомате :)

Answer (score 2):

Например, в Activity2 записывать в SharedPreferences состояние - показывать или не показывать кнопку в Activity1. А в Activity1, в методе onResume проверять, что там записано

Answer (score 1):

Если активити 2 еще не открыто, то экшнбар еще не создан в нем, поэтому обращаться к его полям рано. Как вариант сделайте какой нибудь флажок, который выставляйте true или false, и при переходе на второй активити проверяйте этот флажок, и в зависимости от него скрывайте или отображайте элемент меню